# Как получить HWND окна в котором рисует OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Мне нужно получить HWND или ID потока окна текущего процесса (не моего, я делаю DLL инъекцию) в котором OpenGL производит отрисовку чтобы установить локальный хук (хук сообщений потока окна) при помощи `SetWindowsHookEx`. Я пытался использовать `wglGetCurrentDC` чтобы потом получить HWND окна при помощи `WindowFromDC` но оно возвращает 0. Однако если установить трамплин на функцию SwapBuffers, тот DC который передаётся туда **не равен 0** и при помощи него можно получить HWND. Ставить трамплин ради получения одного HWND такое себе. Я мог бы использовать перебор всех окон при помощи функции `EnumWindows` но это мне не подходит. Проблема заключается в том что нужное мне окно всегда имеет разное название, разное имя класса и не всегда является родительским. Есть ли ещё какие-то функции в OpenGL с помощью которых можно "добраться" до главного окна без использования трамплина? Может быть можно как-то получить список созданных DC вместо получения текущего или вывести существующие контексты и через них как-то выйти?

Comment: Вопрос задан менее минуты назад, а уже кто-то поставил минус, даже не написал за что. Лол.

Comment: [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid), [`EnumWindows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)

Comment: EnumWindows не нужно знать название окна или класса окна.

Comment: Я знаю что не нужно, однако окно может быть не одно и оно не всегда является окном-родителем. EnumWindows как я уже сказал мне не подходит.